# How can I replace the content in a div tag upon selecting a radio button?

Tags: php, radio-button

I want to make an online poll in which upon selecting any option I want to replace the content of the `<div>` with the result. Is there a simple PHP function to replace the content of a `<div>` tag upon selecting a radio button?

Answer (score 2):

php is a server side scripting language. You need to use javascript. If you want to replace it without reloading the page you will need to use ajax. You have about 5 questions packed into your one, and none of them are entirely trivial.

It sounds like you need to start from scratch and learn php and javascript. I found an online resource that will walk you through the many hours it will take for you to produce this effect: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/creating-a-dynamic-poll-with-jquery-and-php/

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done with PHP.  You need to use Javascript to do it.

[Example here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Form-Control/AnonClickeventHandlerforRadioButtons.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Php is not the way to go with this.  jQuery, though, would be.

```
("#id_of_radio").click(function(){
    ("#div_tag").html("<html code here>");
});
```